# E1776 upon assignment (overloaded) with implicit cast access

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have the code below, where the copy-assignment operator is deleted and an int-assignment operator is emplaced alongside an int-access operator (*not marked* with the `explicit` keyword). The assignment of `b` to `a` only works when explicitly casting to `int` as below, while a simple `a = b;` generates a compilation error of `E1776 function "OverloadTest::operator=(const OverloadTest &)" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`. Is there any explanation for this behavior, which ought to take advantage of the explicit deletion and the implementation of implicit operators? Using MSVC++ 14.15.

```cpp
    class OverloadTest
    {
        int i;

    public:
        OverloadTest(int i) : i(i)
        {
        }

        OverloadTest operator=(const OverloadTest &) = delete;

        int operator=(const int &other)
        {
            i = other;

            return i;
        }

        operator int()
        {
            return i;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        OverloadTest a(1), b(2);

        a = b; // E1776
        a = (int)b; // OK

        int (OverloadTest::* e)(const int &) = &OverloadTest::operator=;

        (a.*(&OverloadTest::operator=))(b); // E0299
        (a.*e)(b); // OK

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what other behaviour did you expect? Note that c-style casts as in `(int)b` enable you to do the most wrong things and are to be avoided in favour of `static_cast` or other c++ casts

Comment: To not need to cast whatsoever while utilizing the assignment operator, given the lack of the `explicit` keyword in the `operator int` and explicit deletion of `OverloadTest operator=(const OverloadTest &)`.


Perhaps it is better understood this way: with `OverloadTest operator=(const OverloadTest &)` deleted and the well-defined alternatives of `operator int` and `int operator=(const int &)` provided, why does it still attempt to use the deleted operator?

Comment: you want `a=b` to implicitly convert `b` to `int` and then call `operator=(int)` ?

Comment: sorry still dont get it, the code you posted is fine, but the question is about `a = b;`?

Comment: if you want `a=b;` to work simply [dont declare the `operator=( OverloadTest&)`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5LWLObajyK2O7Ixg). You are explicitly telling the compiler that `a=b;` is not allowed by deleting it

Comment: btw if that is the question better show the code and the error, if it is not then i have no clue what is it ;)

Comment: "you want a=b to implicitly convert b to int and then call operator=(int) ?" Yes, exactly, I updated my code to illustrate my confusion.

Comment: `= delete` doesn't mean "pretend the operator doesn't exist". A function declared deleted still participates normally in overload resolution - but if it's actually chosen, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not really clear why you expected something else as this is just how deleting a method is supposed to work. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) (emphasize mine):

> If, instead of a function body, the special syntax = delete ; is used,
>   the function **is defined** as deleted. Any use of a deleted function
>   is ill-formed (the program will not compile).

By writing

```
OverloadTest operator=(const OverloadTest &) = delete;
```

you do define the operator, but calling it will make your code ill-formed. I find it difficult to answer more than that, because your example is rather academic. You can make `a=b;` work if you simple do not declare the `operator=(const OverloadTest&)` at all. However, note that then the compiler generated `operator=` will be used to evaluate `a=b;`. Though as your class only has the `int` member you actually cannot tell the difference between calling that operator or your conversion followed by `operator=(int)`. Hope that helps.